# How to inject Node.js environment variables into client-side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In our project we have got client-side JavaScript hosted on Node.js.

This script uses another static content from server (something like `http://host:port/static/content`). We can't use a local path, because this JavaScript could be injected in different sites.

Our development, test and production environments have different host and port settings.
So we have to manualy hard-code these attributes for the different environments.

The easiest way to resolve this problem is to manually parse JavaScript as a string on the server side while preparing a response for the static file.

I think this is not a good idea.

Is there any built-in mechanism in Node.js for this case?

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Why not just use PHP so that the client page gets loaded with the correct settings?

Comment: We have got some back-end functionality on Node.js, a we don't want to use 2 different servers in one project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that the client-side code is invoked from some dynamically-generated HTML.

If the amount of "configuration" data is fairly small, you could pass it via `data-*` attributes in the generated HTML, e.g. `<body data-static="http://host:port/static/content">` or, if it's bigger, in an inline `<script id="config" type="application/json">` element.

The key here is to avoid dynamically generating *code* whose only purpose is to represent *data* (40 years ago Kernighan and Plauger, in *The Elements of Programming Style* wrote that they wondered just how much much of the daily activity in a typical computer center amounted to simply entering parameters via the compiler). With an interpreted language it's easy for the code/data distinction to get blurred, but it's worth keeping them separate in your mind.

P.S. Your English is better than that in most questions I've seen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this script could be injected in different third-party sites and we can't manage/change html code of them. In most cases we will only have one line of code in client-side: <script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_our_js"></script>

Comment: Would you be able to stick a `data-*` attribute onto that single script line and have the client code default to the settings for the production server if the attribute isn't there?

Comment: I got your idea, i think we can use some modification of your variant. Thank you.